# Can I unit test Koin Modules?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, koin

I'm using Koin as my DI framework in an Android project and I want to unit test my modules.

For example: if a class A depends on B and C, test that B and C are being included in the Koin graph and that I'm properly injecting them in the module.

Is it possible?

Comment: https://proandroiddev.com/testing-with-koin-ade8a46eb4d

Comment: @Rod if my answer helped you or if it is correct according to your question, please, considere accepting it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Junit, you can and it's very simple:

Add the Koin Android dependency like below:

```
// Add Maven Central to your repositories if needed
repositories {
    mavenCentral()    
}

dependencies {
    
    // Koin for Tests
    testImplementation "io.insert-koin:koin-test-junit4:$koin_version"
}
```

Your test class:

```kotlin
class CheckModulesTest : KoinTest {

    @Test
    fun checkAllModules() {
        appModule.verify()
    }
}
```

You can check the documentation on the [Verifying Your App](https://insert-koin.io/docs/quickstart/android/#verifying-your-app) section

Comment: This is what I needed. I'll try that later on my project, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You can create a mockModule for test.

```
val mockModule = module {
     single { YourClass }
}
```

And then, you need start koin before your tests

```
@Before
fun setUp() {
    startKoin { modules(mockModule) }
}
```

And finaly, stop koin after your tests

```
@After
fun after(){
    stopKoin()
}
```